# ng-src in ng-repeat not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

i'm totally new to angularjs, and here i'm trying to do is getting a img id from ng-repeat and pass it through a function and getting return a image string, but it shows some kind of errors. please help.

HTML

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="(key, list) in listOfProperties">
  <img ng-src="{{getImageUrl(key)}}">
</tr>
```

JS

```
$scope.getImageUrl=function(key){

 return factory.getImgUrl(key).then(function(data){
    return data
 });

}
```

FACTORY

```
getImgUrl:function(key){
  return $http({

            method:"GET",
            url:somedomain.com/getCoverPicture",
            //This domain will return a image string.
            params:{'key':key}

        }).then(function(response){

            return response.data;

        })

}
```

Comment: Can u pls add the error below

Comment: This is what i'm getting                                                         angular.min.js:118 Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5D

Answer (score 0):

Your getImgUrl function does not return the URL of an image. It returns a **promise** of HTTP response, whose body contains (hopefully) a URL.

`ng-src` expect the URL.

Moreover, `getImageUrl(key)` is evaluated by Angular at eash digest cycle, and you really don't want to make an HTTP query every time the digest cycle runs.

So, you need to get the image URLs upfront (when the controller is instanciated, or when you get your listOfProperties) and store them in your objects. Assuming your listOfProperties is an array, as it should be, and not an object:

```
listOfProperties.forEach(function(property) {
    factory.getImgUrl(property.key).then(function(response) {
        property.imgUrl = response.data;
    });
});
```

And in your view:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="property in listOfProperties">
    <td><img ng-src="{{property.imgUrl}}" /></td>
</tr>
```

Please read [this article I wrote](http://blog.ninja-squad.com/2015/05/28/angularjs-promises/) about angular promises, because you seem to miss some important stuff about them.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<tr ng-init="getImageUrl(key);" data-ng-repeat="(key, list) in listOfProperties">
      <img ng-src="{{list.url}}">
    </tr>
```

.

```
    $scope.getImageUrl = function(key, list){

     return factory.getImgUrl(key).then(function(data){
         list.url = data;
     });
}
```